# Don't decode HTML entities when setting value of <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that writes a string to `<textarea>`.  The string may contain HTML entities (like `&amp;`).  When the string is written to the `<textarea>`, the HTML entities are decoded.

```
var str = 'foo &amp; bar';
form.text.value = str;
```

What happens:

`Textarea: foo & bar`

What I want:

`Textarea: foo &amp; bar`

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit** How can I accomplish this *in javascript*, not PHP?

Comment: Read the answer on the link with 24 up ticks - it's nothing to do with php but more the way a browser renders textarea content

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing there, since writing tags like that into textarea should work as you want (https://jsfiddle.net/41wp4jvs/). are you sure form.text is a textarea?

Comment: @Ness for whatever reason, it doesn't in my browser.  Although your fiddle displays correctly...

Comment: @JB0x2D1 strange. but I really don't think the solution you posted below is any good. it won't catch all cases (there might be other characters that you will miss) and in some browsers it might be seeing double. maybe before you do it try to access the textarea the same way I did in the jsfiddle, eg via id. see if it works for you.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm loading the page on my machine locally so I'm not worried about how other browsers might treat it.  Maybe somebody will come along and figure out what browsers behave this way and hash it out into if firefox then x; if chrome then y; if internet explorer then z.  I'm using the latest version of Chromium on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'foo &amp; bar';
str = str.replace('&', '&amp;');//now str == 'foo &amp;amp; bar'
form.text.value = str;
```